How to get httpservletrequest in aspect advice in service class
I have gone through many different post on SO regarding passing the HttpServletRequest to the aspect. But none of them worked for me. Here the usecase to solve is applying the aspect on service impl class and not on a controller class and get request level details.
I have a created an aspect to apply an advice on the custom annotation that will be placed to the service class where I need to get the request (HttpServletRequest) in it.
Few approaches I have tried :

Autowire HttpServletRequest in your aspect
Use RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() in aspect advice methods
Pass HttpServletRequest as an argument to the pointcut on annotation

Autowire HttpServletRequest in your aspect would require registering a bean for this which will fail giving IllegalStateException as httpservletrequest is a scoped request bean
Using RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() to get the httpservletrequest is resulting into null
Using Pointcut with Before advise like below is not letting aspect work
@Before("@annotation(com.company.services.annotations.EnableAuth) && args( request, ..)")
public void doBefore(final JoinPoint joinPoint, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

}

How can we inject HttpServletRequest to a service layer?
Below is my code:
CustomAnnotation
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface EnableAuth {
}

Aspect
@Component
@Aspect
public class AccessAdvice {

    @Autowired
    private AccessTokenSecretConfig accessTokenSecretConfig;

    public static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_HEADER = "accessToken";

    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.company.services.annotations.EnableAuth)")
    public void invokeAnnotation() {}

    @Before("invokeAnnotation()")
    public void doBefore(final JoinPoint joinPoint) throws IOException {
        ServletRequestAttributes t = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        HttpServletRequest req = t.getRequest();

        final String accessToken = req.getHeader(ACCESS_TOKEN_HEADER);
        
        return;
        }
    }

}

xml config
    <bean id="adminService"
        class="com.company.services.impl.AdminServicesImpl" />
    <bean id="accessTokenSecretConfig" class="com.company.services.config.AccessTokenSecretConfig"/>
    <bean id = "accessAdvice" class = "com.company.services.filters.AccessAdvice"/>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

Admin Controller
@Path("/v1/admin")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public interface AdminController {

    @GET
    @Path("/check/status")
    Response checkStatus(
            @BeanParam RequestContextWrapper contextWrapper);

}

Admin Service
public class AdminServicesImpl implements AdminController {
    @EnableAuth
    @Override
    public Response checkStatus(RequestContextWrapper contextWrapper) {
        return Response.ok().entity("Hello !!").build();
    }

}


There are missing classes and imports in your code. E.g., I have no idea which dependency the annotations in AdminController come from. I also do not know the origin of RequestContextWrapper. Please publish a minimal reproducer, ideally a Maven project on GitHub.

@kriegaex You can find the MCVE at link

I did not run your code in a Tomcat instance, but it looks as if you either need to activate component scan or manually add the aspect as a bean to the XML configuration file. I am kind of an AOP expert, but not a Spring user. I know how to get aspects running in Spring Core or Spring Boot with Spring's own web service annotations, but I do not know anything about the JAX-RS stuff you are using. You see in my answer that it works as I suggested.

@kriegaex Sure, thanks for your inputs. I will try this and see what is the missing piece here.

instead of using Aspect, using an interceptor might be more simpler in your case?

How about using Spring annotations instead of the ones you are currently using?
package de.scrum_master.spring.q78880567;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface EnableAuth {}

package de.scrum_master.spring.q78880567;

public class RequestContextWrapper {
  // Dummy class to make the application compile and run
}

package de.scrum_master.spring.q78880567;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/admin")
public interface AdminController {
  @GetMapping("/check/status")
  ResponseEntity<?> checkStatus(RequestContextWrapper contextWrapper);
}

package de.scrum_master.spring.q78880567;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class AdminControllerImpl implements AdminController {
  @EnableAuth
  @Override
  public ResponseEntity<?> checkStatus(RequestContextWrapper contextWrapper) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body("my response body");
  }
}

package de.scrum_master.spring.q78880567;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Component
@Aspect
public class AccessAspect {
//  @Autowired
//  private AccessTokenSecretConfig accessTokenSecretConfig;

  public static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_HEADER = "accessToken";

  @Pointcut("@annotation(EnableAuth)")
  public void invokeAnnotation() {}

  @Before("invokeAnnotation()")
  public void doBefore(final JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println(joinPoint);
    ServletRequestAttributes t = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    HttpServletRequest req = t.getRequest();
    System.out.println(req);
    final String accessToken = req.getHeader(ACCESS_TOKEN_HEADER);
  }
}

package de.scrum_master.spring.q78880567;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args)) {
      doStuff(appContext);
    }
  }

  private static void doStuff(ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext) {
    try {
      HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("my request body");
      RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
      restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/v1/admin/check/status", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    }
    catch (RestClientException ignored) {}
  }
}

This will log something like:
...
execution(ResponseEntity de.scrum_master.spring.q78880567.AdminControllerImpl.checkStatus(RequestContextWrapper))
org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@16c10558
...


I am building a utility that can work with different applications and hence i wanted to put a custom annotation on the pointcut. Aspect is working as I put custom annotation on the Before advice. But as when i add args(request) to it, the aspect stops working. I need to pass HttpServletRequest in the aspect.

Was anything unclear about my request for an MCVE on GitHub? I cannot compile, run or debug prose or incomplete code.
